# Imprimir matriz con función write()

Tags: c

Estoy intentado imprimir una matriz cualquiera con la función `write()` en vez de `printf` y no puedo conseguirlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int x,i,numeros[3][4];
        /* rellenamos la matriz */
        for (x=0;x<3;x++)
            for (i=0;i<4;i++)
                scanf("%d",&numeros[x][i]);
        /* visualizamos la matriz */
        for (x=0;x<3;x++)
            for (i=0;i<4;i++)
                //printf("%d",numeros[x][i]);
                write(1,&numeros[x][i],6);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 3):

Buen día,

La función `write()` recibe los siguientes argumentos

```
write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

El segundo argumento es un `buffer` y necesita ser declarado en bytes, puedes utilizar `char c[3];` para declarar un buffer de 3 bytes

Puedes pasar el `int` de `numeros[x][i]` al `char c[3]` usando `sprintf()`

Ejemplo funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i,numeros[3][4];
    char c[3];

    /* rellenamos la matriz */
    for (x=0;x<3;x++){
        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            scanf("%d",&numeros[x][i]);
        }
    }

    /* visualizamos la matriz */
    for (x=0;x<3;x++){
        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            sprintf(c,"%d",numeros[x][i]);
            write(1,c,3);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```